# How can I fix member count not working in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a message that when someone joins my server, it shows the current member count and pings them with a welcome message.
Heres what I have now:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  global member_count
  print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
  await member.send(newUserMessage)
  print("Sent message to " + member.name)

  try:
    guild = client.get_guild(1107230973986361424)
    channel = client.get_channel(1108211575900360745)
    mc = guild.member_count
    await channel.send(f"**{mc}** | Welcome {member.mention}, to the server! \nMake yourself at home!")
    print("Sent message to the channel")
  except Exception as e:
    print("Couldn't message the channel: " + str(e))
```

When I run it, it says "Couldn't message the channel: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'"

I have enabled all intents in Developer Portal, and here is the replit link to the full project if anyone wants to see the full code: https://replit.com/@Cryptic1526/HouseHimmelst#main.py

I tried this another way a month or so back, and it ran without an error but when a member joined, it said "None | Welcome @member to the server!..." and not the membercount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If client.get_channel returns None it means it didn't find a channel in the internal cache. In that case, you have to use Client.fetch_channel as it will send a request to get the channel.

```
...
channel = await client.fetch_channel(123)
...
```

Alternatively, enabling the intent for guilds will allow you to use Client.get_channel since enabling the intent will also enable caching for guilds and channels. You can also see what events and caching it allows in the [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.guilds) docs.

Enabling the guilds intent would be as below.

```
...
intents.guilds = True
...
```

If this to be called often, you are likely better off enabling the intent and just using Client.get_channel.